# Bash array saving

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop

The think is that I want to save something to an array in bash. The point is that I want one name of file for one array. So I don't know how much arrays I will have.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A NAMES
index=0
for a in recursive.o timeout.o print_recursive.o recfun.o
do
  NAMES[$index]=$a
  index=$((index+1))
  echo ${NAMES[ $index ]}  
done
```

When I run script with `-x` I can see that NAMES[$index], the index is not there represented as number so the whole thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is at lines 7 and 8. Swap them and it will work.

When `index` have value 0 you set `NAMES[0]=recursive.o`, then increment index and print `NAMES[1]` which not set. And same thing for another elements. Because that there is no output.

Your loop should looks like this:

```
for a in recursive.o timeout.o print_recursive.o recfun.o
do
  NAMES[$index]=$a
  echo ${NAMES[$index]}
  index=$((index+1))
done
```

Comment: Wow, working but why? if i swap the lines i than i should be priting array [index++] where should be nothing.

Comment: @Vrsi How can you expect an element that hasn't been assigned a value to contain something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following:

```
declare -A NAMES
```

This makes an associative array `NAMES`.  Quoting from `help declare`:

```
Options which set attributes:
  -a        to make NAMEs indexed arrays (if supported)
  -A        to make NAMEs associative arrays (if supported)
```

You needed to say:

```
declare -a NAMES
```

Comment: Well sorry for that but its not the reason, I changed that because i had the same idea, but it doesnt help. Im thinking the problem is somewhere in syntax. But you are right there should be -a :)

Comment: @Vrsi You are attempting to print the value after incrementing the array index.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a NAMES

for a in recursive.o timeout.o print_recursive.o recfun.o; do
    NAMES+=( "$a" )
done

for (( x=0; x<${#NAMES[@]}; x++ )); do
    echo "Index:$x has Value:${NAMES[x]}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
Index:0 has Value:recursive.o
Index:1 has Value:timeout.o
Index:2 has Value:print_recursive.o
Index:3 has Value:recfun.o
```

Accessing the index which is not set is throwing it off.

```
NAMES[$index]=$a        #Setting up an array with index 0
index=$((index+1))      #Incrementing the index to 1
echo ${NAMES[ $index ]} #Accessing value of index 1 which is not yet set
```